# IE9 when Zoom the screen Issue

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

in IE 9 related to the browser's zoom function.

In the code below,i have a set of div (class='box', 200pixels wide)) all floating inside a large parent div(class='scrollarea',5.000 pixels wide). The visible portion of the page is controlled by the top most div (class='content',400px wide).

When user selects a link a different div is displayed (using anchor tags).

The issue occurs when you have selected the option "Scroll to div 2" and then you try to zoom out the IE browser window (lets say to 70%) The inside divs are repositioned during the zooming and the initial position is lost. Please notice that this only occurs in IE.

Is there a way to fix this?

```css
 .content
        {
            background-color: Yellow;
            width: 400px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        .scrollarea
        {
            width: 5000px;
        }

        .box
        {
            width: 200px;
            margin-right: 200px;
            background-color: gray;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#area1">Scroll to div 1</a> <a href="#area2">Scroll to div 2</a> <a href="#area3">
        Scroll to div 3</a> <a href="#area4">Scroll to div 4</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="content">
        <div class="scrollarea">
            <div id="area1" class="box">
                DIV 1
                <br />                   
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <div id="area2" class="box">
                DIV 2
                <br />
               
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <div id="area3" class="box">
                DIV 3
                <br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <div id="area4" class="box">
                DIV 4
                <br />
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head><!--[if IE]>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=crap.html">
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

no needs to be IE <= 9 today

Comment: But Client Ask it, So Only